# Is there a way for me to use the COPY command with files in other subdirectories when using Docker?

Tags: docker

The current directory of my project looks like this:

```
project
   \---- file1.dockerfile
   \---- scripts
             \-- venv.sh
             \-- task-name
                       \-- run-script.sh
   \---- data
           \-- data1.json
```

Inside of `file1.dockerfile` I have the following:

```
FROM python:3.10.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts/venv.sh ./scripts/task-name/run-script.sh ./data/data1.json /app/
RUN /app/venv.sh && poetry shell
CMD ["bash", "/app/run-script.sh"]
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/scripts/venv.sh" not found: not found
```

I tried to change the copy statement to `COPY . .` and that seems to not solve anything. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

Poetry is initialized inside of the first shell script.

Comment: What directory do you pass as the context on your `docker build` command?

Answer (score 1):

please check your .dockerignore file as it is possible that venv.sh is matching some patterns there and therefore is not copied.

Comment: In fact, there was a `scripts/` inside my `.dockerignore` file. However, now I'm getting the error `"/scripts/task-name/run-script.sh" not found.`

Comment: Are you getting this error while copying or after that?
Al;so you might try to run it with --no-cache flag to not be limited with previous builds.

Answer (score 0):

There is some points you need to check:

1. check your `.dockerignore` to see f you haven't ignored the file or folder or everything (*).
2. try running with `docker build --no-cache`.
3. how are you running your docker build command? are you using vscode or any tool? make sure you `cd` to your `project` folder.